# most efficient way to convert char vector to string

Tags: c++

I have these large pcap files of market tick data. On average they are 20gb each. The files are divided into packets. Packets are divided into a header and messages. Messages are divided into a header and fields. Fields are divided into a field code and field value.

I am reading the file a character at a time. I have a file reader class that reads the characters and passes the characters by const ref to 4 call back functions, on_packet_delimiter, on_header_char, on_message_delimiter, on_message_char. The message object uses a similar function to construct its fields.

Up to here I've noticed little loss of efficiency as compared to just reading the chars and not doing anything with them.

The part of my code, where I'm processing the message header and extracting the instrument symbol of the message, slows down the process considerable.

```
void message::add_char(const char& c)
{
  if (!message_header_complete) {
    if (is_first_char) {
      is_first_char = false;
      if (is_lower_case(c)) {
        first_prefix = c;
      } else {
        symbol_vector.push_back(c);
      }
    } else if (is_field_delimiter(c)) {
      on_message_header_complete();
      on_field_delimiter(c);
    } else {
      symbol_vector.push_back(c);
    }
  } else {
    // header complete, collect field information
    if (is_field_delimiter(c)) {
      on_field_delimiter(c);
    } else {
      fp->add_char(c);
    }
  }
}

...

void message::on_message_header_complete()
{
  message_header_complete =  true;
  symbol.assign(symbol_vector.begin(),symbol_vector.end());
}

...
```

In `on_message_header_complete()` I am feeding the chars to `symbol_vector`. Once header is complete I convert to string using vector iterator. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: [This `std::string` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) should be helpful.

Comment: If `symbol` is a member variable and empty, this is as efficient as it gets.

Comment: Although I gave the most efficient answer which involves copying, I still don't understand why you need `std::vector<char>` in the first place. Just use `std::string` from the beginning!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist How? I don't know how many characters the symbol will be.

Comment: @bkarj You can use `myStr.append()`, or `myStr.insert()`

Comment: @bkarj how does that stop you from using `std::string`? It has nearly identical interface to `std::vector` (as far as resizing is concerned).

Comment: `const char&` is usually better off as just `char`.  After all, why pass a 64-bit pointer to an 8-bit number when you can just pass the 8-bit number itself?

Comment: @bkarj My answer has the way to do it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck tested `char` vs `const char&`. `char` read my test file in 25418ms while `const char&` read the file in 24802ms. Repeated test several times and got similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to The Quantum Physicist's answer: std::string should behave quite similar as vector does. Even the 'reserve' function is available in the string class, if you intend to use it for efficiency.

Adding the characters is just as easy as it can get:

```
std::string s;
char c = 's';
s += c;
```

You could add the characters directly to your member, and you are fine. But if you want to keep your member clean until the whole string is collected, you still should use a std::string object instead of the vector. You then add the characters to the temporary string and upon completion, you can **swap** the contents then. No copying, just pointer exchange (and some additional data such as capacity and size...).

Comment: thanks guys, both this method and .append enhance the speed tremendously. On average 20736ms vs 35459ms. I'll take this over .append because of it's simplicity and its being 20ms faster than .append over an average of 10 comparisons. Every little bit counts for the main files which are 1000 times larger than my test files.

Comment: you mentioned the swap function, which doesn't copy but just swaps pointers. I'm curious, let's say you have a function that returns a string and you have a local string variable in that function to construct the return string. When you return the temporary string variable does the compiler copy the it to the value returned or does it swap?

Comment: @bkarj It will swap - but only since C++11, though. If you compile against an older standard, it will do a copy. Have a look at [rvalue references](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) (in very short: std::string offers a constructor/assignment operator with this 'mystery type' mentioned at page 2). Be aware that - in general - move semantics, as this behaviour is called, only apply if the underlying data type supports it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
std::string myStr(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
```

Although this works, I don't understand why you need to use vectors in the first place. Just use `std::string` from the beginning, and use `myStr.append()` to add characters or strings.

Here's an example:

```
std::string myStr = "abcd";
myStr.append(1,'e');
myStr.append(std::string("fghi"));
//now myStr is "abcdefghi"
```